# how to do make a DataList Paging?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I hava a simple datalist.

```
<asp:DataList ID="MyDataList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" cssClass="row">
    <ItemTemplate>
             <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 img-thumbnail" style="width:300px; height:450px; border: 1px solid black;">
                <div class="text-center"><%# Eval("age")%></div> 
                <br/>
                <div class="text-center"><%# Eval("name") %></div>
             </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:DataList>

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        BindGridData()
    End If
End Sub 

Protected Sub BindGridData()
    Dim sqlConn1 As New OdbcConnection(myConnectionString1)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Try
        sqlConn1.Open()
        Dim Query1 As String = "Select age, name from myTable "
           Dim cmd1 = New OdbcCommand(Query1, sqlConn1)

        Dim reader1 As OdbcDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
        dt.Load(reader1)
        Session("SaveData") = dt
        MyDataList.DataSource = Session("SaveData")
        MyDataList.DataBind()
        reader1.Close()
        sqlConn1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

My question how to make a DataList Paging? For example, at the end of my DataList I want: `(1) (2) (3) (4) (...)` kind of like a GridView

I am already saving my SQL query in session, inside `bindgriddata()`. maybe I can use that?

I know in GridView it's simple, you just do the following and its works but how can I do this using DataList?

```
Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView1.DataSource = Session("SaveData")
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: You should look into the `DataPager` Control.

Comment: thanks, i never heard of datapager but i will look into it